# rospy.Time.now() sometimes returns 0

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm trying to run this code:

```
  prevTime = rospy.Time.now()
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            currentTime = rospy.Time.now()

            delT = currentTime-prevTime
            
            print("Previous time:",prevTime.to_sec())
            print("Current time",currentTime.to_sec())
            print("Time:",delT.to_sec())

            rate.sleep()
```

to get the time of the while loop, because I have a function of time that needs it. Sometimes when running this, prevTime becomes 0:

```
Previous time: 0.0
Current time 1266.097
Time: 1266.097
Previous time: 0.0
Current time 1266.107
Time: 1266.107
Previous time: 0.0
Current time 1266.117
Time: 1266.117
Previous time: 0.0
Current time 1266.127
Time: 1266.127
```

And other times it works as intended:

```
Previous time: 1263.221
Current time 1263.321
Time: 0.1
Previous time: 1263.221
Current time 1263.331
Time: 0.11
Previous time: 1263.221
Current time 1263.341
Time: 0.12
Previous time: 1263.221
Current time 1263.351
Time: 0.13
```

Wondering what the issue could be, and how to stop it from becoming 0

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388660/rospy.time.now()-sometimes-returns-0./) by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2021-10-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-10-14**:
Are you using simulated time?

**Comment by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on 2021-10-14**:
Yes, running the simluations in Gazebo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`prevTime`  may sometimes initialize before the first `/clock` message, so it defaults to 0.  If you use a non-deterministic method of starting nodes, e.g., `roslaunch`, the startup order can vary, so this will happen sometimes but not others.  As noted in the [`rospy` Time overview](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time#Getting_the_current_time), one workaround is to loop the assignment until it returns a non-zero value:

```
prevTime = 0
while not prevTime:
    prevTime = rospy.Time.now()
```

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2021-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1